# Calling Azure Function app works in console but not in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-functions

So I created a function which is a Get request. All the function does is retrieves some data from an SQL database and returns it.

I call this function in a console app, just to test it, and all is working as it should.
I then copy the code and paste it into my xamarin.forms app for android.
When I run it it immediately gives me a 404 Not found response.

Any idea why it's not working in the xamarin app but is working in the console app?

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://{MySite}.azurewebsites.net/api/{myfunction}/"))
        using (var httpContent = CreateHttpContent(new DiaryDate() { Date = DateTime.Today }))
        {
            request.Content = httpContent;
            
            using (var response = await client
                .SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
```

CreateHttpContent just converts the given object to JSON.

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: @Jason Sorry, hit post before finishing. Kids!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the URL to https scheme (**https**://{MySite}.azurewebsites.net/api/{myfunction}/). Firstly, there is no reason for choosing non-secure channel. Azure Function side won't require any change to use https. Secondly, as pointed out in the other answer, there is restriction in client side for http which would require tweak to unblock.

UPDATE: In this particular call, you are using Http GET, but sending a request content (json of `DiaryDate` object). So, it will send that via query string in the the URL. Though I am not yet sure how it's working in console app (might be something to do with how it's handled in Xamarin/Mono http handler v/s that of .net core in console app in GET request), but it should be **[POST](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#define-operations-in-terms-of-http-methods)** surely. Can you change `HttpMethod.Get` to `HttpMethod.Post` in the line where you are creating `HttpRequestMessage`.

Comment: https made no differernce

Comment: Are you able to access any other public site from the app? Or you can check connectivity  by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity.

Comment: I can access other azure functions from the same site. It just seems to be this one function that is not working in xamarin. The other thing to note is it executes very quickly to give the 404 response. Even when there is no data to return, the console app takes longer, say 5 to 10 seconds.

Comment: When you say "I can access other azure functions from the same **site**", by "*site*" did you mean your Xamarin app or something else?

Comment: I have 3 different functions within the function App. 2 of them work fine in the xamarin app. 1 don't. all 3 work in the console app.

Comment: In this particular call, you are using Http GET, but sending a request content (json of DiaryDate object). Shouldn't it be POST? Though I am not yet sure how it works in console app (might be something to do with how URL is formed) , but can you change  `HttpMethod.Get` to `HttpMethod.Post` in the line where you are creating `HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Would be interesting to know why Console App doesn't require this.

Comment: Great. Yes will update the answer on the console app part.